# Android app crashes on load - classNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-intent

This has been driving me mad for a couple of days :)

IDEA is my weapon of choice.  During an editing session of inconsequential changes (or so I thought) of adjusting layouts, nudging buttons a few pixels left to line up etc I compiled and ran the project.  I got a ClassNotFoundException when my app starts.  It is thrown by java.lang.Bootloader.  I put a breakpoint on the call to the Bootloader and can see that the offending class is my main application class.  Here's how it looks:

```
public class Rands extends Application{

    public static SharedPreferences preferences;

    private static ArrayList<Favourite> favourites;

    private static Rands instance;

    public Rands(){
        instance = this;
    }
```

and in the manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="rands.mycompany.com"
      android:installLocation="preferExternal"
      android:versionCode="8"
      android:versionName="0.8">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application android:name="rands.mycompany.com.Rands"
                 android:icon="@drawable/icon"
             android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity android:name="rands.mycompany.com.RandsMainActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
              android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity android:name="rands.mycompany.com.MainMenuActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
              android:label="MainMenuActivity"/>
```

This is where things get funky.  There is NOTHING of relevance in logcat.  I see the app copying, installing and starting then I get the exception.  The exception occurs before the constructor on my application class is called.  If I load the project in Eclipse, it works fine.  I load in back into IDEA and I get the exception.  I have two phones, a Desire with 2.3 and a Tmobile Pulse (Huawei) with 2.2.  It happens on both phones and in the emulator.  If I run the app outside the IDE (i.e. from the launcher) it runs fine.

I make these assumptions:

1. As there is nothing in logcat, it smells like a platform bug
2. As the project works fine in Eclipse, I'm assuming that my manifest and application class are fine.

I've also tried

```
<application android:name=".Rands"
```

Any clues?

Cheers

Comment: You have application android:name="rands.mycompany.com.Rands"
and activity android:name="rands.mycompany.com.Rands" ? How?

Comment: @appserv that really shouldn't matter.
I'd suggest update, clean rebuild, close and restart eclipse. Delete app from phone try again.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.  I changed the app name and company name manually to protect confidentiality (I'm working for someone else). I've edited the post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finished my project in Eclipse then came back for another go at this weird problem.

I have no idea why, but creating a new project from the existing sources worked right away.

I moved the project folder out of my workspace, deleted everything except my src and res folders (no assets) and the manifest then created a new project from existing sources.

Go figure...

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer, Simon--I had the same problem. I could run the app just fine from Eclipse, but if I created an APK it crashed on state. I checked in my code, checked out a fresh working copy, imported it as a new project and it was working again.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped you.  Some funk in the ADT perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

you have already specify the package name in menifest tag so don't redeclare it in activity tag, below code will work for menifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="rands.mycompany.com"
      android:installLocation="preferExternal"
      android:versionCode="8"
      android:versionName="0.8">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application android:name="rands.mycompany.com.Rands"
                 android:icon="@drawable/icon"
             android:label="@string/app_name">

    <activity android:name=".Rands"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
              android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainMenuActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
              android:label="MainMenuActivity"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Application and Activity objects are both named as "rands.mycompany.com.Rands" maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Sorry, typo in my post.  Now fixed.  Thanks,